# Server without www returns 404

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, web

I'm running Apache2 on Debian Jessie, when i try to enter my site without www. it returns a 404 page.

What i have in apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/sites/example.com"
   ServerName www.example.com
   ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/sites/example.com"
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/chain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/key.pem
</VirtualHost>`
```

Now , there are no other definitions in "sites-enabled" that mentions the site

1- Both example.com and www.example.com have the same ip ( Not a DNS problem )

2- There are no extra configurations in "sites-available"

3- https://example.com works fine but http://example.com returns a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `<VirtualHost *:80>` that has no `ServerName` , and apache used default server hostname which was `example.com`